# Ubuntu 18.04 computer consuming high percentage of RAM when in idle state

Tags: 18.04, ram, process

My Ubuntu 18.04 with a RAM of capacity 7.58 GB is using 4GB RAM when none of the applications is running in the foreground.
I also once killed the gnome-shell itself that reduced gnome-shell's RAM usage from 450 MB to 300 MB  (it did not restart itself though, so I restarted computer manually). Is so much of RAM usage on an idle desktop is ok.

Result of "free -m" command:

**When the computer is freshly started**:

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7759         3621        2125       159    2011         3698
Swap:         12287           0        12287
```

**When 13 chrome tabs are open**

```
free -m
             total        used        free      shared      buff/cache   available
    Mem:     7759         6788        134       308         836          376
    Swap:    12287        212         12075
```

**Result of** ***free -m && htop***

[image: Result of *free -m && htop*]

Comment: First, read https://www.linuxatemyram.com then please show us the result of _free -m && htop_ by highlighting the resulting text, copy with Ctrl-Shift-C, return here, click [edit], and paste the text into your question.

Comment: @K7AAY I have added the required additional information